# How to create buttons and make them change color, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand what the problem is. Do I have to give them unique names? If so how can I do that?

```
var co = document.querySelector("div");

var buttons = [];


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    buttons.push("button");
    co.appendChild(button);
    }

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may push the `button` variable, not the string.

```
buttons.push(button);
```

For iterating the buttons, you may take the `length` property for iterating all buttons.

```
for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
```

Don't forget to declare the index variable `i` at top.

```
var i;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fully example of what you want :)

```js
var co = document.querySelector("div");
var colors = ["blue","red","green","orange","black","violet","blueviolet"]
var buttons = [];


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    button = document.createElement("button");
    buttons.push(button);
    co.appendChild(button);
    }

for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    }
```

```html
<div></div>
```